# Update statement not executing inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Please help me with this.

I have a php code which search first for the records that will be needed to inserted to another table

here is my code:

```
//search for split values (capacitors)
$capacitance =mysql_query("SELECT itemno, wwpn,  SUBSTR(val, 1, LENGTH(val) / 2) as capacitor,
                           SUBSTR(val, LENGTH(val) / 2+1) as capasitance
                           FROM   bom_csv WHERE boardnumber ='$board' and bom_csv.qty<>'' and bom_csv.qty !='qty';");
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($capacitance))
 {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $row['itemno'];
    echo $row['capacitor'];
    echo $row['capasitance'];
    echo $row['wwpn'];
    echo "</pre>";
    $capacitor = $row['capacitor'];
    $capacity =$row['capasitance'];
    $adi_pn=$row['adi_pn'];
    $itemno=$row['itemno'];

    //insert into via update
    $update =@mysql_query ("UPDATE bom_crunching SET capacitor ='$capacitor', capacitance ='$capacity' WHERE boardmodel ='$board' and adi_pn ='$adi_pn'");
    if ($update)
    {
        echo "OKAY!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOT OKAY!";
    }
 }
```

While executing it, I am not getting any errors. However, when I look at my query browser it doesn't have any data inserted. 
The result I want is to insert all the records in the table via update statement because it has a default value of null.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you get echoed : Okay or not okay..and have you checked you are getting nay row form you query or not

Comment: @RahulMishra  i am getting okay which means there's no error in my code, but when I look it into database there's no record updated.

Comment: are you getting capacitor and capicrance echoed?

Comment: @RahulMishra yes i am getting it.

Comment: where is your variable $board defined...and what i contains

Comment: code seems ok the problem may be in your where condition double check the where condition

Comment: Try this query:
mysql_query ("UPDATE bom_crunching SET capacitor =' ".$capacitor." ', capacitance =' ".$capacity." ' WHERE boardmodel =' " .$board." ' and adi_pn =' " .$adi_pn.' ");
    if ($update)

Answer (score 0):

First step, change the line:

```
 $update =@mysql_query ("UPDATE bom_crunching SET capacitor ='$capacitor', capacitance ='$capacity' WHERE boardmodel ='$board' and adi_pn ='$adi_pn'");
```

to:

```
 $update =mysql_query ("UPDATE bom_crunching SET capacitor ='$capacitor', capacitance ='$capacity' WHERE boardmodel ='$board' and adi_pn ='$adi_pn'") or die( mysql_error() );
```

So NOW you will be informed what is the problem, than we can help you better.

;)